# How to set low priority for :slug state in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I am using Angular UI Router , and I have setup two routes

One for all the content pages like /about, /terms etc

```
$stateProvider.state('sidebarPages.page', {
            url: ':slug',
            views : {
             ...  
            }
});
```

And now I want to add another for other pages like our-team

```
$stateProvider.state('sidebarPages.page', {
                url: 'our-team',
                views : {
                 ...  
                }
 });
```

The problem is that the second state is ignored when I go to page /our-team and the first one is executed instead which is :slug , and could accept everything.

Is there a way that I can create these two states, one for specific pages , and one that will accept everything and put it in slug param , and based on param I can then bring it from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAN4o41RwR7xGVLd81uO?p=preview). The order decides. Create states with known names, then the one with the slug:

```
    // States
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
          url: "/home",
          templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      })
      .state('other', {
          url: "/other",
          templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      })
      .state('slug', { 
          url: "/:slug",
          templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      })
      ;
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAN4o41RwR7xGVLd81uO?p=preview)